# DateTime format Issue using Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a date format which works on machine with date format day/month/year not in month/day/year.Pls help me to rectify the issue.

```
string startdate =DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text + " 00:00:00").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + " 00:00:00");
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work? I'm sure that it will always be able to parse a date if you provide it in the correct format, so is there some specific format that you expect it to parse?

Comment: @Guffa it is not working on month/day /year format

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` to parse the date in specific format. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to use it.

In your case you can use something like this:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", provider).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: It throws a error no overload for method parse exact takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Developer yes, sorry about that. I fixed the code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

add this in your web config

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

in teg

```
  <system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you can approach this question a couple different ways.  Here are three off the top of my head:

1) [Use the DateTime.ParseExact method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

2) [Change the Regional settings in your operating system.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307938)

3) [Change the culture configuration in your web.config.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx)